# Fixtures causing problems when migrating

Tags: django, django-south

One of my apps has an initial_data.json file in /fixtures, which works great when using vanilla django to specify some initial data. However, when migrating using South, when it steps through 'Loading initial data for ' I get an IntegrityError, because duplicate data already exists. This makes sense, because my migration didn't empty the table, so the initial data from previous calls to syncdb is already there.

How can I either 1) tell South to not load initial data while migrating, or 2) modify initial_data.json or other django files so that duplicate data errors are handled gracefully, instead of crashing the migrate process in south?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

migrate using the --no-initial-data option